# Null request id when subscribe to the topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, amazon-sns, messaging, spring-cloud-aws

i want to make an subscriber from my java spring cloud app , this is my receiver class:

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/mytopic1")
@RestController
public class PurchaseTransactionsSubscriberController {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PurchaseTransactionsSubscriberController.class);

    @NotificationSubscriptionMapping
    public void handleSubscriptionMessage(NotificationStatus status) {
        logger.info("Received subscription request!");
        status.confirmSubscription();
        logger.info("Subscription confirmed!");
    }

    @NotificationUnsubscribeConfirmationMapping
    public void handleUnsubscribeMessage(NotificationStatus status) {
       logger.info("Received unsubscription request!");
        status.confirmSubscription();
        logger.info("Unsubscription confirmed!");
    }

    @NotificationMessageMapping
    public void handleNotificationMessage(@NotificationSubject String subject, @NotificationMessage String message) {
        logger.info(message);
    }

}
```

my application.yaml

```
aws:
  region: eu-west-2
  access-key: acesskey
  secret-key: secretkey
  sns-endpoint: endpoint that i paste in endpoint section when i made subscription in aws console
```

```
@Configuration
public class AWSConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("${aws.region}")
    private String awsRegion;

    @Value("${aws.access-key}")
    private String awsAccessKey;

    @Value("${aws.secret-key}")
    private String awsSecretKey;

    @Value("${aws.sns-endpoint}")
    private String snsEndpoint;

    @Bean
    public AWSCredentials credentials() {
        return new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
    }

    @Bean
    public AmazonSNS amazonSNS() {
        return AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials()))
                .withEndpointConfiguration(
                        new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(snsEndpoint, awsRegion))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public NotificationStatusHandlerMethodArgumentResolver notificationStatusHandlerMethodArgumentResolver() {
        return new NotificationStatusHandlerMethodArgumentResolver(amazonSNS());
    }

    @Bean
    public NotificationHandlerMethodArgumentResolverFactoryBean notificationHandlerMethodArgumentResolverFactoryBean() {
        return new NotificationHandlerMethodArgumentResolverFactoryBean(amazonSNS());
    }

    @Override
    @SneakyThrows
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
        resolvers.add(notificationStatusHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
        try {
            resolvers.add(notificationHandlerMethodArgumentResolverFactoryBean().getObject());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But when i make an subscription the error i receive in backend is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0H8u.png)
Do you guys have some ideas why it gives me this error?
The subscription has the pending confirmation so it did not work